# Efficiency of passing values and objects to nested functions in javascript

Tags: javascript, function, oop, scope, nested

I'm trying to go from procedural programming to object-oriented programming in javasript, because I need to make my code easier to understand.

I suspect I will need to sacrifice SOME code efficiancy for readability, but I still want it to be the main focus of my programming style. I really don't care about new programming paradigms if they are less efficiant, though.

The code:

```
function app(){
    var cnv = document.getElementById('cnv1');
    var ctx = cnv.getContext('2d');

    var life = setup('app');    //builds an object

    cnv.addEventListener('mousemove', MyMouseOver, false);

    //requestAnimationFrame polyfill

    loop();

    function loop() {
        requestAnimationFrame(loop);
        if (life.screen.name == 'loading'){
            runLoading(life.screen);
        } else if (life.screen.name == 'mainMenu'){
            runMainMenu();
        }
    }

    function runLoading(screen){
        //does stuff with the screen object
    }

    function MyMouseOver(MyMouse) {
        if (MyMouse.pageX != undefined && MyMouse.pageY != undefined) {
            var x = MyMouse.pageX;
            var y = MyMouse.pageY;
        }
        else {
            x = MyMouse.clientX + document.body.scrollLeft + document.documentElement.scrollLeft;
            y = MyMouse.clientY + document.body.scrollTop + document.documentElement.scrollTop;
        }
        x -= cnv.offsetLeft;
        y -= cnv.offsetTop;
        life.mouseX = x;
        life.mouseY = y;
        console.log(life.mouseX + ' - ' + life.mouseY);
    }
}
```

I shouldn't pollute the global namespace so I should place all my functions in one big function. OK, so that makes sense. After all, I just call it once.

But that means that all my functions and the life object that contains all my variables that I use share the same scope - nesting further will effect performance since all these functions are called repetedly, so I could use the life object directly...

...but then I can't change it in case of a naming conflict.

The questions:

1. **Looking at the eventlistner - what's better just passing the event and write the data to the life object directly or return the values?**

Spontaniously, I'd say that I'd need to create extra overhead in terms of functions that are created and destroyed on each use (which can be a lot), and make the code harder to read, but maybe I'm wrong.

2. **Should I stop passing values and objects to functions and instead just use the life object directly for manipulated data in all my functions?**

My main concern is that as the project grows, so would the life object...but would that slow down the performance significantly, or is javascript good enough at handling objects? Is there something else I missed?

3. **Looking at the loop function - will just passing the screen part of the life object speed up the processing of the screen objects values?**

Thank you for your input.

Comment: 1) 2) 3) it doesnt matter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. It's an event listener, so you can't return values directly to the your main thread. Function creation overhead could be significant in tight loops, but seems you are not creating the event listener every time.
2. It's good enough for handling objects most of the time. Don't prematurely optimize, understand how the gc works.  Design your code to how you think it may evolve.
3. Yes it will if the compiler did not optimize this part automatically.  But most modern compilers should be able to.